# Play and record 16-bit PCM (raw) audio bytes in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, audio, media-player, naudio

Are there any standard Microsoft components that will allow the following from a WPF application:

- Record (default) PC microphone input to 16-bit PCM audio byte array chunks, and
- Play 16-bit PCM audio byte array chunks on the (default) PC speaker

I have tried to investigate whether I could somehow use the [SoundPlayer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer(v=vs.110).aspx), [MediaElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement(v=vs.110).aspx) or the [MediaPlayer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer(v=vs.110).aspx) components, but I don't really think any of them fit the bill. If I'm wrong, please provide a bit of input on how to go about this.

I can use the great [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio) library by [Mark Heath](https://markheath.net/) to accomplish it, but if at all possible I would like to avoid taking on a dependency outside of the .NET Framework.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid there's nothing built into the .NET framework to do this, which is why libraries like NAudio exist.

Comment: Thank you! I will probably end up using NAudio then :-)